# Dynamically component isnot loading on First click

Tags: lightning-aura-components

After clicking "**Edit product**" button,"Show modal" method will call in javascript side.

- If I click button first time "lgt_EditRecord" isnot
  loading.Status becomes "Error"

> ***DebugLogs:***

[image]

- If I click second time "lgt_EditRecord" is loading.(its working as
  expected!!!)

> ***Debug Logs here:***

[image]

> ***Expected:***

I need to Load "Lgt_EditProductComponent" at first click.

> ***Code Snippets:***

```
 showModal: function(component, event, helper) {
 document.getElementById("Bundleproduct").style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById("searchproduct").style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById("Productservicemainheader").style.display = 'none';

 var target = event.getSource().getElement();
 console.log(event.getSource().getElement());
 console.log($(target).parent().attr('data-selected-Index'));
 var rowId = $(target).parent().attr('data-selected-Index');
 var edit = component.get("v.SelectedWrapperItems");
 var spinner = component.find("spinner");
 component.set("v.rowNum", NaN);
 //console.log('target==',target);
 console.log($(target).parent().parent().parent().find("tr.selected"));
 $(target).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");
 $(target).parent().parent().parent().addClass("selected");
 console.log('record id::::::' + edit[rowId].owOLI.Id);
 component.set("v.EditWrapperItems", edit[rowId]);

 var btnName = event.getSource().get("v.label");
 console.log('btn name------>', btnName);
 var editable;
 if (btnName == 'Edit Product') {
     console.log('call');
     editable = true;
 } else if (btnName == 'View') {
     console.log('editable');
     editable = false;
 }
 var editId = component.find("edit");
 console.log('editId' + editId);
 $A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
 var sBody = component.find("spinnerBody");
 $A.createComponent(
     "c:lgt_EditRecord", {
         "recordId": edit[rowId].owOLI.Id,
         "editable": editable
     },

     function(newButton, status, errorMessage) {
         console.log('newButton------>', newButton);
         console.log('status---->', status);
         console.log('error message', errorMessage);

         //Add the new button to the body array
         if (status === "SUCCESS") {
             var body = component.get("v.body");
             if (body.length == 0) {
                 body.push(newButton);
                 component.set("v.body", body);
                 document.getElementById("searchproduct").style.display = "none"
                 document.getElementById('prodServList').style.display = "none";
                 //$A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
             } else {
                 body = [];
                 body.push(newButton);
                 component.set("v.body", body);
                 document.getElementById("searchproduct").style.display = "none"
                 document.getElementById('prodServList').style.display = "none";
                 //$A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
             }
         } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
             console.log("No response from server or client is offline.");
             //$A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
             // Show offline error
         } else if (status === "ERROR") {
             console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
             //$A.util.toggleClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
             // Show error message

         }
     }

 );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the component as dependency you are creating dynamically.

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://c:componentNameCreatingDynamically" />
```

More you can read about on salesforce docs for [aura:dependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_dependency.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much.It works.I read doccument "<aura:dependency> in the component’s markup to explicitly tell the framework about the dependency. "...how that Logic works here.Can you please explain me

Comment: the comment section is not intended for follow up questions or extended discussions.